# Solvable Groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, field-theory, galois-theory

Does there exist a group $G$ such that every subgroup $H$ is solvable, but $G$ is not solvable. I know that if $G$ is solvable, then every subgroup $H$ is solvable, but I want to know if there is a possible example of every subgroup being solvable, without the entire group being solvable.

Comment: Maybe consider a non-solvable group of smallest possible order.

Comment: @NoahOlander Of course. I confused OPs problem with "every subgroup normal." You would have to prove, first, that there exist non-solvable groups, however. The canonical family (tracing back to Galois) is $S_n,n>4$, of course.

Answer (score 1):

The alternating group $A_5$ is an example which is not solvable but all its subgroups are solvable. You can look [here](http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Subgroup_structure_of_alternating_group:A5) to see the subgroup structure of $A_5$, and notice all the subgroups are solvable.

Comment: How would you go about showing this, I'm not convinced that every subgroup of $A_5$ is solvable.

Comment: $A_5$ is the smallest nonabelian simple group. So the composition factors of any smaller group are abelian.

Comment: @Jordan which subgroup are you not convinced is solvable?

Comment: Also as pointed out, all you need to know is there exists a smallest non solvable group, so subgroups of the smallest nonsolvable  can not be solvable.

Comment: $|A_5|=2^2.3.5$. The *possible* orders of its subgroup are of the form $p$ or $p^2$ or $p^2q$ or $2.(odd)$ for some prime divisors $p,q$ of $|A_5|$. By Sylow theory (and some other theorems) it can be shown that groups of these specified orders are always solvable. [In my opinion, the reason that *$A_5$ is non-solvable group of smallest order* considers *all groups of order $\leq 60$*; but here I am considering groups of order dividing $60$ only, which are sufficient for the question.